# Generating rooted tree in Python

Tags: python, tree, graph-theory, networkx

I need to generate all possible rooted tree structures that results in m-leaf nodes. Vertices in the tree could have degrees ranging from 1 to m-1. Each tree is a weighted, directed graph.

I've come across a package in Python called networkx and it contains a number of graph generators built-in.  How can I use this package to define and generate these graphs ? Appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "rooted"? How are the directions and weights decided in this case? Randomly?

Comment: I was considering something like this:
`P,Q,R,S->P,Q,(R,S)-> P,(Q(R,S))-> (P,(Q(R,S)))`

    

directions are from  left -> right and weights could be set arbitrarily. I'm considering all variations of trees that could be constructed using m- leaves where the merging of nodes could be in any depth level. In this case above, the leaves would be `P,Q,R,S` and the root of the tree is `(P,(Q(R,S)))`